# React Native Error - undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0 _reactnavigation.switchnavigator)')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting this error: undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0 _reactnavigation.switchnavigator)')

I'm building out a React Native template using this link: https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-firebase-authentication-7652e1d2c8a2

Here's my App.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Platform, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { SwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
// import the different screens
import Loading from './Loading'
import SignUp from './SignUp'
import Login from './Login'
import Main from './Main'
// create our app's navigation stack
const App = SwitchNavigator(
  {
    Loading,
    SignUp,
    Login,
    Main
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading'
  }
)
export default App
```

My package.json file shows:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.0-rc.2",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure without setting up the code myself, but it looks like react-navigator might have changed up the API a bit. Try importing and using createSwitchNavigator() instead of SwitchNavigator(), and look here for more documentation on the config:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html

Editing to put the code in here so you don't have to go through the links:

Change import from react-navigation to:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

Change switchNavigator constructor call to:

```
export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
    Loading,
    SignUp,
    Login,
    Main
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Loading'
}));
```

This is the recommended setup from the docs, seen at [Snack Example](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v3) with each of the Routes being stackNavigators. Not sure if that's how you've got it set up otherwise, but I'd just take a look at the example there to figure out how the new parts are set up.

Comment: When I use createSwitchNavigator() instead, I get a new error - Can't find variable: createSwitchNavigator

Comment: Did you add it to the import from react-navigation? e.g.
    `import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'`

Answer (score 0):

Read document of Do react-navigation .here is [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html). Change like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Platform, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation' /////change here
// import the different screens
import Loading from './Loading'
import SignUp from './SignUp'
import Login from './Login'
import Main from './Main'
// create our app's navigation stack
const App = createSwitchNavigator ( ///////// change here
  {
    Loading,
    SignUp,
    Login,
    Main
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading'
  }
)
export default App
```